# jquery load event sometimes dont work, why?

Tags: jquery, events, load

i use something like this

```
$(img).bind('load',function(){
       console.log('loaded');
});
```

and obviously it works, but when the page is loading images from cache
the event isn't triggered.

how can i fix this situation?

Answer (score 4):

This event isn't triggered in some browsers if the image is cached, to get around that you need to check the `.complete` property, like this:

```
$("img").one('load',function(){
       console.log('loaded');
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

The `.one()` ensures it doesn't fire twice, the `.each()` part is manually firing the event for cached images that aren't doing a `load` event themselves.

Comment: I was having a problem because of the image caching when using this plugin https://github.com/gongshw/jquery.areaSelect.js

When refreshing the page, the selections disappear. Your solution fixed my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Fount it!
each image has a .complete property(boolean) so i just need to check that before i bind a load event.